# User guideline in Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, appcelerator

Is it possible to implement user guideline into apps in Appcelerator? Something like this :

[User guideline like this][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bOss.png

I am trying to have some arrows pointing to some buttons and tell users what these buttons do.

Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is completely possible in Titanium. It all depends on how you want the introduction/user-guidelines of the app.

Some basic points to note while creating such UI:

- You can use plain image files of the screen and guideline text on it and then you can show these image files in any form you want like, ScrollableView, ScrollView, simple Views
- You can use animations also while showing the guidelines.
- If you want to add some text on guideline pictures, then you will have to figure out the ways so that the arrow pointing at the picture must point on correct element, e.g. in above picture you mentioned, the arrow is exactly in the middle of the picture, so you do not need to calculate the position of arrow pointer as Titanium by default place elements in middle in **absolute or vertical** layout.
- If you want guidelines text available in different languages, then you can also use Titanium localization implementation.

Finally, there are many ways to do it, it depends on your app's requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out a way which is to add a view programmatically and set the ZIndex to (1), and add a button on top of that, just having the same effect that I want.

Comment: In **absolute** layout, views added in hierarchy are set zIndex in increasing order. e.g. If your parent View has 3 child views - A, B, C... then C will be on topmost, B will be below C, and A will be below C. So you can simply add a View and then a button, then this button will be top on View by default in **absolute** layout.